# Only setting the "checked" value of selected radio button while removing the attribute for other buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am going out of my mind and cannot seem to figure out the logic here.

I have 4 Radio buttons

```
(0) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" checked="checked">
( ) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
( ) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
( ) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
```

When the user selects the second button I want the markup to perform as such:
I have 4 Radio buttons

```
( ) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
(0) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" checked="checked">
( ) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
( ) <input type="radio" name="radioGroup">
```

I have tried various forms of `click` events to set the now unselected box to not have the checked attribute.

I have it so it sets the box attribute to checked but it isn't deselecting the now unchecked button
http://jsfiddle.net/Dnd2L/27/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the checked attribute is used for a default value. Radio buttons are evaluated on the form submit. You may have more luck using onclick.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdo1" name="rdoTest" onclick="ChangeStatus();" />

<script>
        function ChangeStatus()
        {
              $('#rdo1').prop('checked', true);
        }
<script>
```

You handle true/false attributes differently in jquery

Comment: I was able to get it to function how I want however the box does not actually show the selection http://jsfiddle.net/Dnd2L/35/

Answer (score 0):

Among a group of radiobuttons, only one can be checked. This means you don't have to "uncheck" it manually, the browser does it for you.

If you modify the code at http://jsfiddle.net/Dnd2L/35/ and remove/comment out this line: `$("input:radio").removeAttr('checked');`, the buttons will show correctly which one is checked.

Comment: When you "inspect element" on the different buttons the attribute checked is present for each radio button.